# How to display averaged + Standard deviation parameter in one cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset with particular parameter (accuracy) for which I need to create 2x2 pivot table (conditions) where the asked parameter is averaged and showed with std.

I can do either (average OR std) but not together simultaneously. Is there a way to do so?

[image: scr]

the above shows the data sample and the result I wnt to get. Only it should display the avg + std together in one cell

Comment: Please add screenshots of some small sample data and expected output, filled manually at least.

Comment: @ omegastripes thank you, I have added a screenshot

Comment: What do you mean with "display the avg + std together in one cell"? concatenate the two strings? add them?

Comment: Still can't see on screenshots how it should display the avg + std together in one cell. Please fill cells manually to show what output you need for exact given data on the screenshots.

Comment: Is this helpful?  for example write in the cell: ="std:"& STDEV.P(your range) & ",dev:" & AVEDEV(your range)"

Comment: Just concatenate the two values.